# Disable alert when manually deleting a sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there a way in VBA to disable the alert that pops up when MANUALLY deleting a sheet (right-click sheet and delete)? I have seen `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, however, this seems to only work for me when deleting a sheet using VBA (`Sheets("Sheet1").delete`). I am trying to disable the alert for the whole workbook when you manually right-click on a sheet and click delete.

As a quick background to the question, I am trying to eliminate the need to confirm deleting a sheet when presenting the workbook in meetings. While going through the sheets, I often double click on pivot tables to view detail, and I would like to eliminate the pop-up alert when I delete the generated sheet. Disabling the alert would need to occur in VBA since it needs to be toggled on and off automatically when entering or exiting the presentation view.

Comment: Not sure if this is acceptable, but I'm thinking of a workaround that would eliminate the need to manually delete each individual sheet generated by double-clicking the pivot tables - the new sheet(s) would be deleted automatically once you select another sheet?

Comment: @ERic, Excel don't have any option or command to stop the Alert messages as you have written about the message appears while delete the sheet manually. VB script is the only method TO STOP ALERT MESSAGES.

Answer (score 0):

**There is NO any command or Option or Method which could stop the "Excel alert/warning messages".**

**Even the "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" doesn't works when use through Immediate Window in VBE. The only way is to use the VBA script.**

*So that the below written code can be used as Module for the Sheet which you want to DELETE without confirmation message.*

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_without_warning()

 Dim i As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
If Worksheets(i).Name Like "Sheet5" Then Worksheets(i).Delete
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**Note:** if you want to delete more that one Sheet, use wild card method & replace command line 6 with this:

if Worksheets(i).Name Like "Data*" Then Worksheets(i).Delete

Excel will deleted all sheets without warning has name starts with **Data**.

Answer (score 0):

If new sheets are created only by double-clicking pivot tables, this might be a suitable solution

Placed in `ThisWorkbook`, the code bellow will delete any new sheets after moving to another sheet

---

```
Option Explicit

'Place this code in ThisWorkbook module

'Expects that all new sheets are generated by double-clicking a pivot table

Private pivotWs As Worksheet

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set pivotWs = Sh
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Not pivotWs Is Nothing Then
        If Sh.Name = pivotWs.Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            pivotWs.Delete
            Set pivotWs = Nothing
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```